# Importing TSV Data with python to an arango Database

Tags: python, database, arangodb

I'm currently working on a project, with which I have big TSV files and need to import them in a database. I need a noSQL database so I chose Arango. With arango, we can't import TSV files in python. Only JSON files. But, we can import TSV files with PowerShell.

The files are around 1Gb and once they are imported, I will need to do daily updates to the database, with the same TSV files, but that could be modified.

What are the best options?

- Convert tsv files to json with panda in my python program, then bulk import (I think this cause memory issues)
- Just use with open() and insert documents line by line (Again, memory issue, but you guys may have a solution)
- Use the powershell way to import the data. The only problem with that is that I use docker, therefore I can't simply run a powershell script.
- Use another database

Also, what would be my best bet for the daily updates, taking into consideration the memory issues?

Comment: Actually you can import tsv files with arangoimport: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangoimport.html

Comment: only with powershell/command prompts

Comment: You can invoke external processes with Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html - but you may as well read the TSV data and transform it JSON using Python. I don't see any memory issues, simply use `for line in file` or `file.readlines()` which iterate over the lines of a text stream.